# MySQL: SELECT with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, join

how can I join two tables and make the second optional?

```
SELECT t1.title,SUM(t2.seconds) AS seconds 
FROM operation t1 
  LEFT JOIN workhours t2 ON t1.id = t2.pid AND t1.status='0' 
ORDER BY t1.tstamp DESC
```

This query shows only one result but there is a second one withour any worktime on it. How can I make sure that the data from t1 will always be displayed even when there is nothing in t2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `GROUP BY t1.title`:

```
SELECT t1.title,SUM(t2.seconds) AS seconds 
FROM operation t1 LEFT JOIN workhours t2 ON t1.id = t2.pid AND t1.status='0' 
GROUP BY t1.title
ORDER BY t1.tstamp DESC
```

In general, if title is not unique, you should group by unique key.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to always have results from the first one that do not match with any of the second one so you must use **Left Outer Join** if the other table does not have any matching result with the second one it will always show the result of the first one independently if the second one matches the join or  not.

Comment: `left join` and `left outer join` is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue may be in the "SUM(t2.seconds)" parameter on your select.

Try adding ISNULL(SUM(t2.seconds), 0).

If that doesn't work, you might try a SQL IF statement or CASE and check a column on t2 for nulls.